# Определение видимости блока

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть задача: определить реальный просмотр изображения (блока). Для этого я определяю позицию блока на странице, учитываю скролл, свойства display и visibility, активность вкладок в браузере. Остался один момент - определение видимости относительно других элементов. Т.е. нет ли элементов, которые позиционированы прямо над моим изображением. Может кто сталкивался или у кого есть идеи как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь, на самом деле это практически невозможно. Представьте, что вышележащий элемент:

- Имеет `opacity`, отличную от 1
- Имеет `background-color` с альфа-каналом, отличным от 1
- Имеет бэкграундом градиент с элементами прозрачности
- Наоборот, полностью прозрачен, но имеет перекрывающий непрозрачный `:before`/`:after`
- Полностью перекрывает нижележащий элемент, но не перекрывает `:before`/`:after` нижележащего элемента
- Имеет размеры один в один, но повернут на сорок пять градусов
- Представляет собой изображение с поддержкой альфа-канала
- И еще куча вариантов.

Самое близкое решение, которое стоит взять - специальный псевдокласс `:visible` у jQuery, `jQuery(element).is(':visible');` вернет вам результат требующейся проверки. Разработчики jQuery уже наверняка встали на все существующие грабли и реализовали защиту от них.

Comment: Мне кажется вы немного не на тот вопрос ответили. Из доков jQuery: "Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document". То есть видно его реально или нет, в этом селекторе не учитывается. Посмотрите на фразу в вопросе "...прямо над моим изображением..."

Comment: @tutankhamun да, вы правы, сейчас отредактирую.

Comment: Ну, скажем так, Вы меня убедили подзабить на это)

Comment: @Gomonov Боюсь что пока иначе никак. Javascript не всесилен в браузере и не все решит большинство указанных пунктов

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, используйте z-index

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #000; height: 200px; width: 200px; background: green; z-index: 1000; position: relative;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid #000; height: 200px; width: 200px; background: red; position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;"></div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nsdw8vea/)

Comment: Вы додумали мой вопрос. Мне ничего делать не надо меня и так и так устраивает) Мне надо только понять, видно изображение или нет.